# jQuery validation unable to validate my information

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-validate

I need to do a validation for my username during registration, unfortunately I'm not able to get any information from the screen and there is no response when I clicked submit button.

**UPDATED**

This is the login and signup script that I doing, but I'm unable to display my error message and also display incorrect css style when doing the checking.

[image: http://img809.imageshack.us/img809/9749/af86.png]

Here is the screencast http://www.screencast.com/t/hQdRev1HOnh

```
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            //* boxes animation
            form_wrapper = $('.login_box');
            function boxHeight() {
                form_wrapper.animate({marginTop: (-(form_wrapper.height() / 2) - 24)}, 400);
            }
            ;
            form_wrapper.css({marginTop: (-(form_wrapper.height() / 2) - 24)});
            $('.linkform a,.link_reg a').on('click', function(e) {
                var target = $(this).attr('href'),
                        target_height = $(target).actual('height');
                $(form_wrapper).css({
                    'height': form_wrapper.height()
                });
                $(form_wrapper.find('form:visible')).fadeOut(400, function() {
                    form_wrapper.stop().animate({
                        height: target_height,
                        marginTop: (-(target_height / 2) - 24)
                    }, 500, function() {
                        $(target).fadeIn(400);
                        $('.links_btm .linkform').toggle();
                        $(form_wrapper).css({
                            'height': ''
                        });
                    });
                });
                e.preventDefault();
            });
            //* validation
            $('#login_form').validate({
                onkeyup: false,
                errorClass: 'error',
                validClass: 'valid',
                rules: {
                    username: {required: true, minlength: 3},
                    password: {required: true, minlength: 3}
                },
                highlight: function(element) {
                    $(element).closest('div').addClass("f_error");
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        boxHeight()
                    }, 200)
                },
                unhighlight: function(element) {
                    $(element).closest('div').removeClass("f_error");
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        boxHeight()
                    }, 200)
                },
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    $(element).closest('div').append(error);
                }
            });
            $('#reg_form').validate({
                onkeyup: false,
                errorClass: 'error',
                validClass: 'valid',
                rules: {
                    reg_username: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 3,
                        remote: {
                            url: "http://127.0.0.1/check_username.php",
                            type: "post"
                        }
                    },
                    message: {
                        reg_username: {remote: jQuery.format("{0} is already in use")}
                    },
                    reg_password: {required: true, minlength: 3}
                },
                highlight: function(element) {
                    $(element).closest('div').addClass("f_error");
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        boxHeight()
                    }, 200)
                },
                unhighlight: function(element) {
                    $(element).closest('div').removeClass("f_error");
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        boxHeight()
                    }, 200)
                },
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    $(element).closest('div').append(error);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

And this is my username checking source code. Although i change the return the string result I won't able to show my error message.

```
    include('../inc/dbconn.php');

if (isset($_POST['reg_username'])) {
    $reg_username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['reg_username']);
    $check_for_username = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM customers_register WHERE username='$reg_username'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($check_for_username)) {
        echo 'false';
    } else {
        //No Record Found - Username is available
        echo 'true';
    }
}
```

---

Here one of my part of javascript

```
 $('#reg_form').validate({
        onkeyup: false,
        errorClass: 'error',
        validClass: 'valid',
        rules: {
            reg_username: {required: true, minlength: 3, remote:"check_username.php"},
            reg_password: {required: true, minlength: 3}
        },
        message: {  
            reg_username: {remote: jQuery.format("{0} is already in use")}
        },
        highlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('div').addClass("f_error");
            setTimeout(function() {
                boxHeight()
            }, 200)
        },
        unhighlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('div').removeClass("f_error");
            setTimeout(function() {
                boxHeight()
            }, 200)
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            $(element).closest('div').append(error);
        }
    });
```

and this is my check_username.php

```
<?php

include('../inc/dbconn.php');

if (isset($_POST['reg_username'])) {
    $reg_username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['reg_username']);
    $check_for_username = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM customers_register_user WHERE username='$reg_username'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($check_for_username)) {
        echo "TRUE";
    } else {
        //No Record Found - Username is available
        echo "FALSE";
    }
}
?>
```

And this is html source code

```
            <form method="post" id="reg_form" style="display:none">

            <div class="top_b">Sign up</div>
            <div class="alert alert-login">
                By filling in the form bellow and clicking the "Sign Up" button, you accept and agree to <a data-toggle="modal" href="#terms">Terms of Service</a>.
            </div>
            <div id="terms" class="modal hide fade" style="display:none">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
                    <h3>Terms and Conditions</h3>
                </div>                    
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <a data-dismiss="modal" class="btn" href="#">Close</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cnt_b">      
                <? echo '<input type = "hidden" name = "client_mac" value = "' . $client_mac . '">'; ?>                      
                <div class="formRow">
                    <div class="input-prepend">
                        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" id="reg_username" name="reg_username" placeholder="Username" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="formRow">
                    <div class="input-prepend">
                        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span><input type="password" id="reg_password" name="reg_password" placeholder="Password" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="formRow">
                    <div class="input-prepend">                           
                        <span class="add-on">@</span><input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="email" placeholder="<?= $email ?>" />

                    </div>
                    <small>The e-mail address is not made public and will only be used if you wish to receive a new password.</small>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="btm_b tac">
                <button class="btn btn-inverse" name="oprf" value="signup" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Please show your html code as well and make sure jquery laod in the page on top of the validation function. and it will be better if you will tell us what error your are facing .

Comment: Are you displaying from conditionally? so that you have use `display:none` and have include `jquery.validate.js`

Comment: @Roopendra actually the `display:none` are not related with `jquery.validate.js` function, it just my `CSS` design which is fade in/out to another screen.

Comment: Okay i got your point regarding display none, but you are using `$('#reg_form').validate({` its needed `jquery.validate.js`

Comment: Please don't use any of the `mysql_*` functions anymore. They're deprecated. Eiter use `mysqli_*` or even better, parametrized PDO queries.

Comment: @Roopendra `jquery.validate.js` are included in my development. `<script src="../lib/validation/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>`

Comment: your script is working here http://jsfiddle.net/42GjC/

Comment: @Roopendra working for the normal validation which is required field but not working with username checking and submit

Answer (score 0):

It seems your jquery code is fine. Can you please debug your script like this:-

```
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    include('../inc/dbconn.php');

    if (isset($_POST['reg_username'])) {
        $reg_username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['reg_username']);
        $check_for_username = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM customers_register_user WHERE username='$reg_username'") or die(mysql_error());
        // If 0 reocrd found then username available
        if (mysql_num_rows($check_for_username) > 0) {
            echo 0;
        } else {
            //No Record Found - Username is available
            echo 1;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: I didn't get an error because there is not response when I clicked `Submit` button.

Answer (score 0):

**Quote OP:**

> *"This is the latest update seem I can get the `TRUE` and `FALSE` from the validation but the problem is although I have enter the value **it still pop out the error** and I won't able to submit my registration."*

Your code...

```
if (mysql_num_rows($check_for_username)) {
    echo "TRUE";
} else {
    //No Record Found - Username is available
    echo "FALSE";
}
```

Your `true/false` logic is completely backwards.  In the jQuery Validate plugin, if a method returns `true` it means the element passed validation and `false` means the element failed validation (triggers the error message).

You are echoing `"TRUE"` when the username is already in your database, however, you should be echoing `"FALSE"` to indicate that this field has failed validation.

---

**EDIT:**

As per documentation:

> The response is evaluated as JSON and **must be `true` for valid elements**,
>   and can be any `false`, `undefined` or `null` for invalid elements...

http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/

Comment: trying to exchange this 2 conditions but it doesn't work as well.

Comment: @JienWai, what are you talking about? According to your OP, it wasn't working at all, so how could it possibly be any worse?  Send a server response of `true` and it _passes_ validation. Send a server response of `false` and it _fails_ validation... it's that simple. Refer to the documentation: http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method

Comment: fixed with change `TRUE` and `FALSE` to small capital letters. But my own error message doesn't work.

Comment: @JienWai, that's not what you originally asked about.  [Have you read the documentation yet?](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method)  _"**The response** is evaluated as JSON and must be `true` for valid elements, and can be any `false`, `undefined` or `null` for invalid elements, using the default message; **or a string**, eg. 'That name is already taken, try peter123 instead' **to display as the error message**."_

Comment: In other words, if you use `false`, you'll only get the default error message.  If you want a custom error message, you must construct it on the server and return it as a string instead of `false`.  See:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method